# Angular bootstrap calendar. How to limit the year shown in dropdown to 5 years from current year

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

I have angular bootstrap calendar I am trying to set the calendar drop down to show only next 5 years and not more than that. Currently it is showing +10 years and - 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

use maxDate function in angular bootstrap

in the input tag `[maxDate]="maxDate"`

in typescript

```
maxDate:any;
inside ngoninit
this.new = Date();
this.maxDate = {year:this.now.maxfullyear()+5,month:1,day:1}
```